# Remove integer and only display decimal point in Python?

Tags: python, integer, decimal, rounding

I am trying to calculate the square root of a number to where it looks like this:

```
Enter number for square root: 2
---------------------------------
.41
```

However, with the current code I have:

```
def calc(self, event=None):
    try:
        self.result_var.set("The square root of %s is %0.2f" % \
            (self.number.get(), sqrt(float(self.number.get()))) )
```

I get 1.41.

How do I remove the "1" so it only displays ".41?"

Comment: cast to int and subtract? `num - int(num)` , just like all the oldsckool cool c kids.

Comment: The square root of 2 isn't 0.41. Your current code is right. If you want to remove the integer part, you can do `n % 1`.

Comment: @Blender, I know, however I need it to display only the decimal places. To be more correct, I'll edit my print to "The approximate decimal square root is"

Comment: @Blender -- Note that `% 1` doesn't give the decimal part for negative numbers.  That's not a concern if you're getting the number from a square root, but ... in general I suppose it could be.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `divmod` to split a number into it's integer part and decimal part:

```
>>> divmod(1.41,1)
(1.0, 0.4099999999999999)
```

so,

```
intpart,decimalpart = divmod(number,1)
```

---

I suppose to get this to work for negative numbers, you'd need something like:

```
_,decimalpart = divmod(abs(number),1)
```

or more succinctly:

```
decimalpart = abs(number) % 1
```